# Save on a list more than one input

Tags: python, list, append

I have this:

```
for i in range(3):
    i = input("write name")
```

I would like to append the `i`  inputs to a list named `a`

Comment: So what is the issue with your try to append to list?

Comment: I defined a = [] inside the for cycle, then the result was always the last input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should:

1. Create an empty list called "a".
2. Assign the corresponding input to each loop to a variable (e.g: input_word)
3. Append that variable to your list

```
a = []

for i in range(3):
    input_word = input("Write name:")
    a.append(input_word)
```

Or more simple, you assign to the list "a" the result of  `input()` each time you repeat the loop (which is basically the same as above).

```
a=[input('Write name:') for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this within your `for` loop by creating the `a` list up front and then appending to it inside the loop:

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
    name = input("write name")
    a.append(name)
```

Or you could use Python's list comprehension syntax to do this in a single statement:

```
a = [input("write name") for i in range(3)]
```